# Setting Authorization header in XMLHttpRequest changes HTTP verb

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Today I found a strange behavior of XMLHttpRequest. When I am calling a GET service I found that if I do not set the Authorization header the request from firefox is same. But if I add the "Authorization" header firefox first send a request with "OPTIONS" then it sends a "GET" request.

I know that the verb "OPTIONS" must be handled in server side but I was just wondering why XMLHttpRequest behaves like this. Though it is a cross domain request, why browser first send the "OPTIONS" request. Why adding a "Authorization" header changes the behavior.

Here is my Javascript code and Fidler Inspector report.

```
    var  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            alert("OnReadystatechange + " + xmlhttp.readyState + " " + xmlhttp.status);
           if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
              if ( xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                   }
                   else {

                   }
             }
             else
                   alert("Error ->" + xmlhttp.responseText);
          }
```

And the fiddler response with Authorization Header

[image]

[image]

But when I do not add the Authorization header the browser directly sends the GET request no OPTIONS request.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The HTTP `OPTIONS` request is used to "preflight" the cross-origin `GET` request, before actually sending it.

> Unlike simple requests, "preflighted" requests first
>   send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the
>   other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe
>   to send.  Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may
>   have implications to user data.  In particular, a request is
>   preflighted if:
>
> - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used    to send request data with a Content-Type other than
>     application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
>     text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the
>     server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is
>     preflighted.
> - **It sets any header that is not considered simple.** A header is said to be a simple header if the header field name is an ASCII case-insensitive match for **Accept**, **Accept-Language**, or **Content-Language** or if it is an ASCII case-insensitive match for **Content-Type** and the header field value media type (excluding parameters) is an ASCII case-insensitive match for *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*, *multipart/form-data*, or *text/plain*.

So in your case, setting the Authorization header is causing the request to be preflighted, hence the `OPTIONS` request.

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

[Spec on Cross-Origin Request with Preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0)

Comment: Yes I understand the preflight request. But just wondering why adding the Authorization header makes the preflight request. None of the two requirements (As mentioned in the link) are being fulfilled here.

Comment: The authorization header qualifies as a `custom header`. see the second requirement.

Comment: It seems so. Otherwise it didn't make any sense. I thought that this header is a standard header as it is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests). Anyway thanks a lot for the information.I am new to Javascript. The link you mentioned really helped me a lot to understand the preflight request.

Comment: I also don't understand why Authorization is, in the context of CORS, considered as a 'custom header', while it is clearly part of the [http protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields). This means that in CORS scenarios where you use token authentication (which I believe is kind of a best practice in any CORS scenario), essentially *every* request, including all simple GET requests will be pre-flighted and as a consequence take considerably longer.

Comment: @VincentSels The results of initial preflight request can be cached by browser, depending on value of response header `Access-Control-Max-Age`.

Comment: @levi: that would be nice, but the request url must be exactly the same, *including url parameters*, as defined by the [W3C CORS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/): "The url field value is a case-sensitive match for request URL". 
This means that in practice, these 'get' preflight requests are practically never cached...