# XMLHttpRequest doesn't send some headers

Tags: javascript, ajax

The title explains my problem clearly. I am testing the AJAX requests of my application but I cannot send some headers, for example Authorization header.

For testing I use [this](http://headers.jsontest.com/) endpoint to echo me the headers I sent. Here is my javascript code:

```
var loadDoc = function() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        };
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "http://headers.jsontest.com/", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "JWT token");
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I can send the exact same request with python's requests module. But I can't send it with XMLHttpRequest. XMLHttpRequest can send the Content-Type header and the server echoes me the headers but not Authorization.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you having the same problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410925/setting-authorization-header-in-xmlhttprequest-changes-http-verb

So a OPTION request is send first? (that won't have the header in it)

Comment: it's a CORS issue, plain and simple - see the response to the OPTIONS request - `access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type` ... there is no `authorization` in the allowed headers, so it is not an allowed header, so the request fails

Comment: Yeah. It was a cors related issue. I have tested on my remote web server, and I have allowed "Authorization" header in cors options and it worked.